# Responsive design layout autosize

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a responsive layout using bootstrap. To keep it simple, I want to implement a row that can contain one or two columns. If there is only one column it should fill all space if there are two it's 50%. If the screen is small then the second column is moved bellow the first.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="region1" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div id="region2" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

So is it possible to make the first column expand if there is enough space without using javascript. I know with javascript I could just toggle some classes but I wanted to keep it to html/css only.

The second div can be empty or hidden sometimes. In that case the first one needs to cover all horizontal space

Comment: Your code works as you want it to: see http://jsfiddle.net/raad/zrnfxfpg/

Comment: "If there is only one column it should fill all space if there are two it's 50%" > CSS Flexbox can do that. Or you'll have to use JS. Or if you use some CMS or any server-side language you can check if there is a column or more, and apply the relevant class.

Comment: The second div can be empty or hidden sometimes. In that case the first one needs to cover all horizontal space.

Comment: _"The second div can be empty or hidden sometimes"_ Well, it needs to be either one or the other, because the solution is different depending on whether the div needs to be hidden or not. FYI An empty div is almost, but not quite, hidden when using the default Bootstrap styling.

Comment: Ok, the div can be hidden. Just to clarify, my problem is that the grid system of bootstrap only takes in account the number of columns, so in my case it always covers half the space for large screens even if there is more available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to really accomplish, you could perhaps use a media query.

If you want to just accomplish what you described in the OP using markup exactly like the example where the column values will be either 6 or 12 grid units, the following will work:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) { /* or 1200px if you just want it to affect the lg devices */
   .col-md-6:last-child:nth-child(odd)  { /* definitely NOT supported in IE8 */
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/vru7y5nw/)

Basically this rule says: if the viewport is greater than or equal to 992px (the md Bootstrap breakpoint), make the width 100% for any column with the class .col-md-6 that is the last child of it's parent AND is an odd child (so the first, third, fifth, etc).

This rule should work on all modern browsers (as well as IE9), but will not work on IE8.  The fallback scenario is that it will simply show the column as 6 grid units instead of 12.

While this works and could be extended for other scenarios, it's highly dependent on your markup so, I recommend that you add another selector to the rows where you want this behavior to apply, so that you can target only specific rows for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bootstrap classes

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="region1" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div id="region2" class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
```

for more info http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: This isn't right - the regions are always vertically stacked and `region2` will disappear on small screen sizes. The OP wanted the 2 regions to be side-by-side (as columns), but stacked on small screens.